# Transform a excel data in R time series

Tags: r, database, time-series, export

I´m trying to transform a excel data into time series in R, But I'm having a issue, the main problem is that i have different categories [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkja1.png], and my data it's supposed to start in 2014 and end in 2023, with seasonality by month.

I tried to use rep before the time series [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RQUM.png], but doesn't work.

And i don't want to the variable "Unidades" be numeric like the image [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYtB.png], i would like to be character.
in
I would like to my data be like the data "global_economy" in the library tsibble, but my data should include month and year and in the global_economy data have just year.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post reproducible data and code instead of picture links

Comment: ^ often, the easiest and most useful way to do this is by selecting a representative part of your data (e.g. `my_data[5:10, 1:4]` is rows 5-10 and columns 1-4 of `my_data`) and then using the `dput()` function to convert that part of the object into code. So `dput(my_data[5:10, 1:4])` will make a recipe that we can run to make a copy of that data with all the same structure / data formats that you have. This is important in R, since many data structures and data formats will print out identically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: dados_brutos <- read_xlsx("Clientes Atendidos e Atendimentos para Previsão.xlsx")

dadosb2 <- dados_brutos %>%
  mutate(mes = rep(seq(1, 12), length.out = n()),
         Ano = rep(rep(2014:2023, each = 12), length.out = n()),
         `Mês e Ano` = NULL)


dados <- as_tsibble(dadosb2)                                                                                                              Thats my code when i do it the following error appears  dados <- as_tsibble(dadosb2)
Error in `validate_index()`:
! Can't determine index and please specify argument `index`.